# Choice Modeling and MaxDiff

Tags: estimation, survey, econometrics, references

I am new to the market research industry and have been exposed to a procedure called MaxDiff. I have seen this also called Best-Worst scaling. I am looking for good literature overview for this method and how it fits with respect to other survey design question choices. I am especially looking for a technical analysis of the method itself rather than an application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that I found on your subject:

TenBerge, J.M.F. (1988) Generalized approaches to the Maxbet problem and the Maxdiff 
problem, with applications to canonical correlations, Psychometrika, 53, 487-494.

I hope this helps a little.